# Udpclient.receive from unknown (random) port

Tags: c#, c++, .net, udpclient

I'm using UdpClient to send a message and listen for a response, like this:

```
Client = gcnew UdpClient();
HostEndPoint = gcnew IPEndPoint(192.168.0.20, 52381);
Client->Connect(HostEndPoint);
Client->Send(Message, Message->Length);
Bytes = Client->Receive(HostEndPoint);
```

I have two similar devices but they respond differently. In the first case, the destination responds on the same port as I send to. So, for example, sending with a random source port of 49542, this happens:

```
 Request: 192.168.1.10:49542 > 192.168.1.20:52381
Response: 192.168.1.20:52381 > 192.168.1.10:49542
```

And with the above code I get the response as expected.

The other similar device however responds with a random port (which changes whenever it is powercycled), like this:

```
 Request: 192.168.1.10:49542 > 192.168.1.20:52381
Response: 192.168.1.20:46468 > 192.168.1.10:49542
```

And in this case, I do not receive the response, Receive() will timeout. I believe I understand why there's nothing received. There's suggestion in .net docs that once you use a IPEndPoint with UdpClient() or Connect(), any other responses are filtered out. So, I'm not even sure why Receive has an IPEndPoint parameter.

I have monitored the communication with WireShark and I can see the messages in both directions. So I know the device is responding I just can't figure out how to receive it in my code.

The best solution I think is to be able to receive any response that arrives to my source random port (49542 above), additionally to specify the destination IP as well, but that may not be needed. Alternatively, to listen for any response from the destination IP, on any port, since I don't see how to know what port the device is responding with.

As best as I can figure out you have to indicate a port # for Receive(IPEndPoint), which usually is the destination port of the message you sent to in the first place - as it is in my code sample (which works with the first device). The random port chosen by Connect can't be listened to, that's the receiving port, but I think Receive listens for the sending port from the device. which is unknown.

I tend to think that the fact that I can't find any information about how this can be done suggests that it can't be done because devices aren't supposed to respond from a random port. But, I've discussed this issue with the manufacturer and they insist it's correct behavior.

Also note, I've tried to create a second UdpClient to listen for the response from the destination IP, but it also requires a port be defined, and there's no way I can tell to know what port to listen for. I have tried UdpClient()->Client->RemoteEndPoint, but I'm pretty sure, this is the endpoint I'm starting with which has the known port, not the random port.

This is the first time I've encountered this and it seems weird to me. The devices are from a major manufacturer though, that surely knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved this. The trick is to not use Connect, but instead to pass HostEndPoint in the Send command. This approach works with both devices.

```
Client = gcnew UdpClient();
HostEndPoint = gcnew IPEndPoint(192.168.0.20, 52381);
// Client->Connect(HostEndPoint);
Client->Send(Message, Message->Length, HostEndPoint);
Bytes = Client->Receieve(HostEndPoint);
```

Although it's working, I'm not completely sure what messages it will allow thru. It might allow any port from the specified IP, or it might allow any response from the specified IP that is directed to the initial random source port. I'm not sure.

Also, I initially thought I might have to set HostEndPoint->Port = 0 between Send and Receive. That works, but it isn't necessary.